# Program Priority on Lubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, cpu-usage, scheduler

Given a single processor virtual machine running lubuntu, I was wondering if it is possible to tie up the processor so that no other program can run any instructions.
For example, if program A and program B were to be run at nearly the same time, is it possible to set the priority of program A (in its source using the setpriority() function) to run before program B and then tie up the processor so that program B cannot execute?

Comment: You're asking whether Linux is preemptively or cooperatively multitasked? I would recommend using those terms in a web search, if you weren't previously aware of exactly what the concepts were called.

Comment: I was not aware but after a quick search I see that linux is of a preemptively multitasking architecture. I assume that, by its very definition, a single process cannot hold the CPU preventing other processes from running?

Comment: Yup! (There's more to it than that, but that's the gist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `kill` with `SIGSTOP` and a pid value of `-1` to stop every process that you can (i.e., have permission to) stop other than init and the calling process, which, if you are root,  should stop every process other than `init` and the process that calls `kill`.

You'd want to use a scripting language rather than the kill binary, as the kill binary would exit after sending the signal and not give the shell you ran the kill binary from would have been stopped, preventing you from launching your app.

E.g., in ruby, you could do,

```
#Broadcast the STOP signal
Process.kill(:STOP, -1)
#Run your process with the playground having been cleared
system('the_high_priority_app')
#Resume the stopped processes
Process.kill(:CONT, -1)
```

The above is a bit of a hack, though, and not very safe if you have many processes that do some IPC by sending the SIGSTOP and SIGCONT signals among themselvesj -- you could be sending SIGCONT to processes that had been stopped by other processes. You could get a list of processes that were stopped at the time of broadcasting the SIGSTOP signal and skip those when you broadcast the SIGCONT signal, but the set of sigstop processes could theoretically change between your scanning for them and your broadcasting of the SIGSTOP signal.

Comment: Ultimately, this was the way to go since eventually the OS would interrupt the program to yield CPU time regardless of process priority

Answer (score 0):

With the right priviliges it is possible to call 'sched_setscheduler' to give a process real time priority. Such a process will not be interrupted by ordinary processes or other real time processes with lower priority. Such real time processes will only lose CPU when they give it up by doing some call like sleep or waiting for IO. They will also be given the CPU back as soon as they are able to work again and the CPU is not needed by any real time process with higher priority.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the preemptive nature of the OS, the CPU will yield eventually regardless of process priority. In this case, priority will only give the process a longer time slice and not completely shut out the other program as desired

Comment: The preemptive nature described by Scott does not live up to the Posix real time extensions defined by POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008. The idea with a real time priority task is that it should not be preempted by any normal task or any lower piority real time task.